# TOTAL VALUE IN POWERBI TABLE AFTER GROUP BY

Tags: group-by, powerbi, visualization, aggregation, summarize

I have a table like this:[image]

I would like to obtain a single row for each combination of product, category and price (I'm not interested in the aggregation per sub product).
All the product in each category have the same price.

I tried to do a group by in different ways but when I show product, category and price in power bi table visualization, it doesn't show the correct total value.

How can I do that?

This is desidered output:
[image]

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: I need a measure that summarize rows for each combination of product category and price, finally I have a table with two rows in my example: product a, catgeory a, 6,5 and product b category a 8,5. Table visualization have to show total value of column price correctly (15)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a measure that should work:

```
MIN PRICE =
IF( HASONEVALUE( Data[PRODUCT] ),
    MIN( Data[PRICE] ),
    SUMX( SUMMARIZE ( Data, Data[PRODUCT], Data[CATEGORY], 
                            "PRICE", MIN ( Data[PRICE] ) ),
          [PRICE] 
    )
)
```

The total row will return FALSE for `HASONEVALUE(Data[PRODUCT]` and true for the table rows. The `SUMMARIZE` statement replicates your table and `SUMX` iterates through it to calculate the correct total.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

Try this measure

```
_PRICE = 
SUMX (
    SUMMARIZE (
        'Table',
        'Table'[PRODUCT],
        'Table'[CATEGORY],
        'Table'[UM],
        'Table'[PRICE]
    ),
    'Table'[PRICE]
)
```

[image: S2]